# How to obtain container Ip from another container?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  node:
    build: ./node/
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ~/src/api:/code
    links:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=dev
      - POSTGRES_ADDRESS=postgres

  postgres:
    build: ./postgres/
    ports:
      - "8000:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pw
    volumes:
      - ~/Postgres/data/:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

But when I access process.env.POSTGRES_ADDRESS in my nodejs, it returns 'postgres'. This is the way I have always done it, and it should return the ip of the postgres container.

Any suggestions to how I can access the postgres container ip?

Comment: Why do you need container IP? you always can access by container name, like `postgres` in your example.

May be there is need to rename this question to "how to obtain container Ip from another container?" because env variable can't be dynamically convert container name to ip address

Comment: and if you need obtain ip address from hostname you can use nslookup: `nslookup postrges`

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thank you. I thought I explicitly needed the ip for this to work in my nodejs app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have access to another container within docker network by container name.

Also docker creates DNS server by ip `127.0.0.11`, and you can ask it "where is my container" like `nslookup postrges`

Answer (score 1):

From the docs: "Environment variables are no longer the recommended method for connecting to linked services."

https://docs.docker.com/compose/link-env-deprecated/

@Bukharov Sergey's comment is the accepted answer:

"Why do you need container IP? you always can access by container name, like postgres in your example. May be there is need to rename this question to "how to obtain container Ip from another container?" because env variable can't be dynamically convert container name to ip address –"

as I did not need the IP, only a way to connect to the container.